# Throw and catch in a get set statement

Tags: java

I have a main class and a employee class. My goal is for the second test to return "wage cannot be negative" due to the fact that the hourly input rate is -20. Instead it is making the total dollars earned negative. What do I have to fix? I feel like my problem is somewhere in the throw catch statement. There's no errors but it isn't showing my quote.

```
package employee;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee ryan = new Employee("Ryan", "Smith", 40, 20);

        System.out.println("Test #1");
        System.out.println(ryan.getFirstName() + " " + ryan.getLastName() + ", worked " + ryan.getHoursWorked() + " hours and earned $"
                + ryan.getHoursWorked() * ryan.getWage());

        Employee hayden = new Employee("Hayden", "Moore", 20, -10);

        System.out.println("Test #2");
        System.out.println(hayden.getFirstName() + " " + hayden.getLastName() + ", worked " + hayden.getHoursWorked() + " hours and earned $"
                + hayden.getHoursWorked() * hayden.getWage());
    }
}

package employee;

public class Employee {
    private String firstName, lastName;
    int hoursWorked, wage;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int hoursWorked, int wage) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        this.wage = wage;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked) {
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }

    public int getHoursWorked() {
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public void setWage(int wage) {
        if (wage < 0) {
            try {
                throw new Exception("Wage cannot be negative");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else
            this.wage = wage;
    }

    public int getWage() {
        return wage;
    }
}
```

Comment: You check the validity of the wage in the setter, but this setter is never called anywhere. You pass the negative wage in the constructor, but the constructor doesn't validate the wage. Also, throwing an exception and immediately catching it doesn't make sense. The whole point of an exception is to warn the **caller** of the method that something is wrong. Don't catch the exception in the setter. And use an appropriate, runtime exception: IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Why do you throw a exception and catch it right after?

Comment: 1. read about constructor
2. debug the source code
3. avoid try/catch for getters and setters, use an init method with validation

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here I can think, you can or put the logic of the exception inside the constructor, or you can create a constructor without the parameters you are using to check the exception and use the getter and setter instead after instance the object. I don't recommend use the setters inside the constructor, the logic gets a little obscure if you do that, but it's something you can also do

Comment: "you can or put the logic of the exception inside the constructor" But wouldn't that be redundant ? To put the control in the setter AND the constructor ?

Comment: Exactly, that's why is better don't give the parameters to the constructor and force the user to use the setters

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing through the setters in your constructor, instead you're assigning the passed value directly, change your constructor to :

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int hoursWorked, int wage) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
    setWage(wage);
}
```

This way, every argument will have to go through the setter.